# Using C# + Mapscript + Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, c#, mapserver, mapscript

Nowadays i'm using Mapscript and C# to generate and display a Mapfile, but in this way i need to create manualy the interface, is there any way to use Mapscript + Openlayers?

Comment: OpenLayers ins Javascript. Why do you want to use it with Mapscript? Is your goal to write C# code that writes Javascript code?

Comment: My goal is to use OpenLayers interface with Mapcript, i want to use the pan, zoom, drag and drog generated by OpenLayer.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need mapscript to achieve what you want.
Simply use the mapserv cgi to publish the layers as [WMS](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html) and then consume the WMS services from a OpenLayers-powered web page.